# Open credential pop up on Windows 10 in Java

Tags: java, windows, credential-manager

I'm developing an application for Windows 10 in Java. My application require credential to call api, and I want to save it to windows credential manager. Because I want users input their account only 1 times (first time they open app), then I can use their credential without asking in the future.

I searched around and knew how to read/write credential to windows credential manager. But I don't know how to open credential popup. I need to open it because people will trust to login Windows more than my app.

The credential popup look like:
[image]

Please share to me if you know a way to open this popup in Java (or in any programming language). Thank you!

A code, or a guide, document to open windows credential popup